# Using F# type providers on top of a DataTable

Tags: datatable, f#, type-providers

I will be spending some significant amount of time trying to understand large chunks of data that are behind an API which returns DataTables for given queries. Here F# type providers would make my life significantly easier. Is there an easy way to build a sequence of strongly typed object from given DataTable object.

One way around is to dump datatable content to XML via WriteXml and than to load it back with XmlProvider but this approach is a bit clunky.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of Type Providers working with databases directly.
See SQL data access section here:
http://fsharp.org/guides/data-access/index.html

My favorite is this one http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/

Comment: Well the source is not SQL db exactly. My API gets me a datatable and that is the only way the data is exposed (some security problems make this API really hard to be extended plus it's a legacy software so I don't want to get into making changes on the server side).

Comment: In this case if your API returns DataTable objects you could save them to your local database using SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer method and use SQL type provider to investigate data.  You can use save to XML with XML type provider as well as you suggested in your question

Comment: I'll bet you could create your own type provider for this sort of thing without too much difficulty. You could use the source for the ExcelProvider as a template to adapt from. https://github.com/fsprojects/ExcelProvider